# Why the wireless connection in linux ubuntu often disabled suddenly?

Tags: networking, unix

I am using linux ubuntu.
When I want to use a wireless or LAN, the connection is often turned off by the sudden. But suddenly the connection back to normal anyway.

Maybe there's anyone who can help me?
Please share...
thanks before.

Comment: Is it different in another OS?

Comment: Maybe a driver issue, try to install the non-opensource driver Do you faced the same problem with Windows ? What's the name of your wifi card ?

Comment: I'm using 2 OS. Windows 7 and linux ubuntu.
But in my windows theres's no problem with the wireless or LAN connection.
I want to use wireless or LAN connection in ubuntu to do the assignment of my lecture. But the connection is disabled.
Actualy I don't know the name of my wifi card, does it matter?
I'm using laptop Toshiba L510.
So, what should I do?